# Shared Hosting IP, server issue

Tags: shared-hosting

I have a domain.com hosted in in shared hosting provider. The dns entries were in cloudflare.

Soon this issue happened. when I open the website domain.com, the pages shown is not of my website. But another.

ie; when i entered domain.com.

The url remains the same. But the page shown is for domain2.com.

The site was working fine. This happened a few days ago.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are both domain.com and domain2.com websites that you have access to in your shared plan, or is domain2.com some totally unrelated customer's site?

Comment: domain2.com is totally unrelated. It's not our website.

Comment: We have little chance of helping you while you are redacting the domains.

Comment: Google "dns test tools" (no quotes) to confirm DNS is working (which is seems to be). Presumably, you've got your site root set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can test if the problem is with your hosting provider by connecting directly to `IP:80` with Netcat / PuTTY / similar and performing the request for your domain manually:

   ```
   GET / HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com
   ```

   If you get a wrong answer, you'll need to contact your service provider and ask them to correct the configuration. The web server needs to be aware that such domain exists and where its document root is. Otherwise it will fall back to the default domain.
2. If the answer from the first test was ok, this might be a DNS related problem. Check that the DNS is pointing to the right IP on a) the *authoritative* name servers b) your local cache.